# Is aq_inner (and friends) still needed on Dexterity-only environments?

Tags: plone, zope, dexterity

I have a browser view that on its call method has something like this:

```
def __call__(self):
    context = aq_inner(self.context)
    parent = aq_parent(context).
    ...
```

Putting a pdb at the beginning and playing with it seems that, for Dexterity there is no need to use it, is that right?

```
ipdb> self.context, id(self.context), self.context.__class__
(<Container at /plone/ausgaben>, 4651890160, <class 'plone.dexterity.content.Container'>)
ipdb> aq_inner(self.context), id(aq_inner(self.context)), aq_inner(self.context).__class__
(<Container at /plone/ausgaben>, 4651890160, <class 'plone.dexterity.content.Container'>)
```

So the result is the same using aq_inner or not.

So the question is: does Dexterity (as self.context and in our project actually everything is Dexterity based) prevent us from having to wrap everything with aq_inner and aq_parent and so on, and instead use directly the objects or `__parent__` pointers?

Comment: I have a suspicion that you would see something remarkably different with id(aq_base(self.context)).  Pretty sure that Dexterity objects are aq-wrapped.

Comment: Indeed, ``aq_base`` has a different id and does not have a path on its __name__, still the question remains unanswered: on Dexterity-only environments can I just forget to have to use aq_inner and friends?

Comment: Guessing that the wrapping is simple/consistent enough that aq_inner won't be needed, but keep in mind that `__parent__` pointers require the aquisition-wrapper, not the other way around -- IIRC `assert getattr(aq_base(self.context), '__parent__', None) is None`.

Answer (score 1):

Like AT contenttypes, DX contenttypes are also aq-wrapped. So you're going to face the same behaviour (issues :-)) as with AT.

As sdupton said in his `aq_parent(instance) == instance.__parent__`. The parent pointer ist still implemented thru acquisition.

But there is a small differences to AT.

If you create a new DX obj the following happens:

1. [createContent](https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/blob/1ac2d02bdf58c264cc4b21664ecccfd1e7d69af6/plone/dexterity/utils.py#L129) will be called which creates the DX obj - At this point the content is not yet aq-wrapped. So if you subscripe the `ObjectCreatedEvent` you gonna have a not aq-wrapped obj.
2. [addContentToContainer](https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/blob/1ac2d02bdf58c264cc4b21664ecccfd1e7d69af6/plone/dexterity/utils.py#L155) will be called, which adds the created DX content to the container. In [`container._setObject`](https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/blob/1ac2d02bdf58c264cc4b21664ecccfd1e7d69af6/plone/dexterity/utils.py#L180) the `ObjectAddedEvent` will be fired. If you subscribe this event you will have a aq-wrapped dx content.

This is different in AT, of course other events are fired for this case, but the AT content is always aq-wrapped (also in the factory, while adding a new AT obj)

Please let me know, if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, still the question was mostly about, once the object is there and you get it somehow (in my example, through self.context), is there any need to still use aq_inner and aq_parent explicitly? Which by the tests I did seemed to me that was not needed.

Comment: If you have a container with attribute `title` and a item in this container with no attribute `title` and you call `item.title`, it will still return the `title` of the container unless you use `aq_explicit`. You have to use `aq_inner` only if you want to access the item only in it's containment (http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/Acquisition.html#additional-attributes-and-methods) - Conclusion: Yes you still have to use aq_explicit, etc. to be sure on what object the value is from. Can you show us the test case?